# Как получить куки с сайта

Tags: python

Имеется такой код:

```
rs = requests.get('https://mysite.ru/api/id=10', cookies=cooks)

dict_cooks = rs.cookies.get_dict()
print(rs.cookies.get_dict())
```

в итоге я получаю:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session-cookie=... for mysite.ru/>]>
```

Проблема в том, что на сайте используется не только `session-cookie`, а еще несколько `id, u_id, XSRF-TOKEN` итд. Как мне остальные куки вывести или записать в переменную?

Comment: Попробуйте через requests.post.

Comment: тут дело в том, что у меня считываются куки из response header, а нужно из request header. Если я правильно понимаю